# Django ORM query taking very long but Raw query runs as expected

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have a simple get query

```
key = TenantKey.objects.get(pk=api_key)
```

When I'm running a load test, for many requests the above query is taking multiple seconds (max 15s) which is very strange. So I ran a raw sql query equivalent to the above ORM like below

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
cursor.execute("SELECT app_tenantkey.key_id, app_tenantkey.name FROM app_tenantkey WHERE app_tenantkey.value=%s",[key])
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Surprisingly this query was way faster than the ORM which is what we were expecting as the table is very small and contains about 20 entries.

I'm also attaching the max durations of both queries just FYI

[Raw Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLYGv.png)
[ORM Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ9Mq.png)

The ORM query is taking almost 100x when compared to time taken by the raw query in similar situation. I want to understand what's causing the ORM is taking so long while the raw is quick.

Comment: Thats odd. Can you share your settings.py file? make sure to hide all the secret keys and database connection details

Comment: In the raw query you are checking using `value` attribute but in ORM you are getting using pk, are you sure you are checking from same table ?

Comment: @Ahtisham 
The value field is set as primary key in the model. Also I'm querying all the fields instead of just two fields in my actual query. This one is just for reference

Comment: @SimbaOG Do you want to see the entire file or a specific section ?

Comment: Entire file would be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what the issue was, it turns out that the issue was not with django's ORM. The real issue was DNS name resolution to the DB. This Query was the first query to the DB that's the reason why only this line took multiple seconds while other query's were running as expected.